# check if native method exists

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am writing a C# wrapper around a third party C++ library and with a new version a method parameter changed from uint to ulong.
I still need to support the old version preferably without changing the wrapper interface.

Now I would need to know if I can call the new or the old method. I already tested that I can call the new method with the old library without a C# exception but of course the results will be wrong.

Is there a way to check if a native method with specific parameter types exists? Or maybe another way around it?

This would one example of a changed method (notice the value parameter):

```
[DllImport("Foo.dll")]
public extern static uint Bar(IntPtr ptr, uint value, out IntPtr optr);

[DllImport("Foo.dll")]
public extern static uint Bar(IntPtr ptr, ulong value, out IntPtr optr);
```

Comment: To avoid problems when you change a parameter type, you should create a second function with a different name, for example `Bar2`.

Comment: There is no way to do this, period. C# needs you to specify the exact calling convention and parameters of the method precisely because it can't know what they are. A library is very poorly designed if, between versions, it changes function signatures -- this is true for unmanaged code as well, since that code will likewise break without being recompiled.

Comment: Read the dll version number?

Comment: @Wimmel, it's a third party dll. I have no control over that sadly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks. I'll have to find another way around that issue then.

Comment: @AlexK. yeah that would be a possibility but how do I know where the dll is? Is there a way to reproduce the DllImport path finding?

Comment: `DllImport` just uses `LoadLibrary` under the covers, so it uses [the same rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682586). But rather than figuring out those, you could just P/Invoke to `LoadLibrary` and [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms683197), then use [`FileVersionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo). (Don't forget a call to `FreeLibrary`, or the reference count will be off.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, cool, thank you very much!

Comment: if anyone has the same problem, you can find the dll path and file version with Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules IF you have already called a method with DllImport (i.e. the library is loaded)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Feature detection when P/Invoking in C# and .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794991/feature-detection-when-p-invoking-in-c-sharp-and-net)